# error when configuring terminus for python in sublime text

Tags: python, linux

Hi i'm a linux user i use sublime text i want to setup terminus for python but when I press build it says /usr/bin/env 'bash' not a directory please help me to fix this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWOXe.jpg)